# phpMyAdmin - 20000 tables, how to track changes

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just installed phpMyAdmin. I want to know how to add tables to the `pma__tracking` table,so  I can track changes in those tables.

Is there a script I can use?

Answer (score 3):

Even though this is an old thread  for the people searching for this might be helpful 
In the PHP myadmin [phpmyadmin 3.7.5-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wJe9.png)
Select your database -> More Options -> Tracking 
Select tables you want and enable tracking

Comment: This seems to me rather involved if the database contains 20k tables, as in the title to this question.

Comment: You can "Check All" at bottom

Answer (score 0):

after you made sure that you have phpMyAdmin configuration storage setup and working correctly,
to enable tracking for a single table in phpmyadmin open the table and at the top bar there is a button called "Tracking" click it then click "Create version" this will add the table you are at to the `pma__tracking` table automatically

Comment: thank u，i knew this,but that's only work for one table,how can i add 20000 tables to pma__tracking in this way?

Comment: is there script to use,so i can add 20000tables in one click?

Comment: there is no option built into phpmyadmin that enables tracking for multiple tables in one click that i am aware of, however you can set the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking_version_auto_create'] = true; (add it to your configuration file if it is not there) ,  If this is set to true and you create a table or view with
CREATE TABLE ...
CREATE VIEW ...
and no version exists for it in pma__tracking , the mechanism will create a version for you automatically, so if you export your database and import it again, it should (in theory) add tracking to all the tables you have in your database.

Comment: Sort of off topic (and obviously I don't know anything about the dataset you're storing), but 20000 tables seems quite excessive...you might want to re-think your database structure. And I agree with what H.M. said, that's a pretty decent workaround as long as your import and export are complete.